# Parsing & replacing multiple links but not when one contains an other

Tags: ruby, parsing, url, substring, gsub

I can't figure out how to (easily) avoid link (2) to replace the beginning of link (1). I'd appreciate an answer in Ruby but if you figure out the logic it's good too.

**The output should be:**

```
 message = "For Last Minute rentals, please go to:
    <span class='external_link' href-web='http://www.mydomain.com/thepage'>http://www.mydomain.com/thepage</span> (1)

    For more information about our events, please visit our website: 
    <span class='external_link' href-web='http://www.mydomain.com'>http://www.mydomain.com</span> (2)"
```

**But it is:**

```
    message = "For Last Minute rentals, please go to:
    <span class='external_link' href-web='<span class='external_link' href-web='http://www.mydomain.com'>http://www.mydomain.com</span>/thepage'><span class='external_link' href-web='http://www.mydomain.com'>http://www.mydomain.com</span>/thepage</span> (1)

    For more information about our events, please visit our website: 
    <span class='external_link' href-web='http://www.mydomain.com'>http://www.mydomain.com</span> (2)"
```

**Here's the code (edited: took out the spans):**

```
     message = "For Last Minute rentals, please go to:
    http://www.mydomain.com/thepage

    For more information about our events, please visit our website: 
    http://www.mydomain.com"

   links_found = URI.extract(message, ['http', 'https'])

   for link_found in links_found          
     message.gsub!(link_found,"<span class='external_link' href-web='#{web_link}'>#{link_found}</span>")
   end
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Are the span indicators `(1)` and `(2)` required?

Comment: @theTinMan no it was just to make the example easier to explain

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that your problem is related to `URI.extract`. When it goes through `message` it's pulling *all* the instances of "http", which, for the first line, would be both "http" inside and outside the `<span>`.

To further clarify, `links_found` would be an array with both `<span...href-web:...` and `http...</span>`. Since you're only passing `link_found` to gsub as the pattern to match, it will replace every object in the `links_found[]` array

Comment: Thanks! It definitely helps understanding the WHY but I can't think of a solution right now...

Comment: Instead of passing `link_found` as the pattern to match, I would either be more specific when passing to `URI.extract`, or add to `link_found` when you pass it to gsub. As an example: `message.gsub('href-web=#{link_found}', ...)`

Answer (score 0):

First, rule one, don't bother with string manipulation or regular expressions for anything but the most trivial things when dealing with HTML or XML. Doing otherwise is a sure recipe for [madness](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/128421).

Instead, save your sanity and go for a real parser. For Ruby I strongly suggest you look at Nokogiri only - it just works.

Consider this code:

```
require 'nokogiri'

message = "For Last Minute rentals, please go to:
<span class='external_link' href-web='http://www.mydomain.com/thepage'>http://www.mydomain.com/thepage</span> (1)

For more information about our events, please visit our website: 
<span class='external_link' href-web='http://www.mydomain.com'>http://www.mydomain.com</span> (2)"

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(message)

external_spans = doc.search('span.external_link')

url1 = external_spans[0]['href-web'] # => "http://www.mydomain.com/thepage"
text1 = external_spans[0].text       # => "http://www.mydomain.com/thepage"
url2 = external_spans[1]['href-web'] # => "http://www.mydomain.com"
text2 = external_spans[1].text       # => "http://www.mydomain.com"
```

`url` and `text1` are the URLs from `span 1` and `url2` and `text2` are from `span 2` respectively.

I'm not sure what you want to do with them, because, after a more-than-cursory glance I couldn't see a difference in your source and desired output, but, once you have them you're pretty much free to do anything. A parser, like Nokogiri, lets you retrieve information from the HTML or XML DOM, replace it, move things around, or even splice in new stuff.

Comment: Thanks! I will try playing around Nokogori tomorrow.

I actually edited the 'message' variable I have as an input. It doesn't have the spans initially.. Sorry!

Comment: Ok, with that edit it becomes understandable. The problem doesn't require Nokogiri though it can help. I'll add to my answer when I get near a computer. Basically though, `URI.extract` is a good starting tool but it doesn't give us enough positional information about the URLs it finds, and without that you can't pinpoint where a substitution should occur.